# how to display 3d building by using MKMapVIew iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mkmapview

I want to show 3d building using **MKMapview** like coming in google map

Desired Mapview showing 3d building:

[image]

my current map is coming like

[image]

I have set `_mapView.showsBuildings  =YES;`

code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D ground = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.58448, -8.93772);
CLLocationCoordinate2D eye = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.58448, -8.93772+.0020);

MKMapCamera *mapCamera = [MKMapCamera cameraLookingAtCenterCoordinate:ground
                                                    fromEyeCoordinate:eye
                                                          eyeAltitude:3300];

_mapView.camera.pitch = 10;
_mapView.showsBuildings  =YES;
_mapView.pitchEnabled = YES;
_mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = YES;
_mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
_mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
_mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
_mapView.camera = mapCamera;
```